# C# how to connect to sql server with sql authentication after making program exe by innosetup

Tags: c#, sql-server

I make a program , using c# and sql server with sql authentication , It works properly in my device , but after making the program setup file .exe extension using Innosetup , i cannot connect to my database , what I've tried is exporting my database in script , and run the script on another device , but it does not work , I think I need to create port or something to connect to this database , or in my app.config change the server name

Here is my connctoin string

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MarketDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AmanjCenter2Entity.csdl|res://*/AmanjCenter2Entity.ssdl|res://*/AmanjCenter2Entity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=RABAR;initial catalog=MarketDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What is your code? What error did you get? Give people more details..

Comment: I got no error in my code . I made my program setup.exe file , after installing it , it works until it needs database , when it uses database it closes my program

Comment: I have no error in code , I only changed the device , it lost its connection and gives me an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two points of failure here:

1. Data source: Data source name is machine name. Is your target machine name "RABAR"? I guess not. If your database is installed on that machine, you can change data source to `data source = (local)`.
2. Integrated Security: You have set `Integrated Security = true`. This causes problem on target machine because you will have to configure SQL Server user and windows user accordingly. Instead of that trouble you can create a SQL Server user and configure your connection string that way i.e `User Id = [SQL Server User]; password = SQL Server User's password`.

HTH

Comment: Yes I My machine name is RABAR , I changed to (local) and in my sql server , i changes windows authentication to sql authentication with user name and password , and changed my connection string to them , still got same exception

Comment: Now we got to see some error messages to diagnose it further.

Comment: Beside this , I changed my servername to `Localhost\Sqlexpress`  Its working fine thanks